# On /users method id parameter does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

Calling `/users` method with `id` parameter returns a list of users and not the user expected.
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users?id=23234

Could be a documentation "bug" on help page:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` has been removed from the documentation for this method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not how you are supposed to call the users endpoint.  Try this:

[`http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/23234`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/23234)

You can do this with a vectorized string like so:

[`http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/23234;2598;1`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/23234;2598;1)

You aren't supposed to pass id in as a url parameter.  It is actually part of the url.

Your call is being interpreted as:

[`http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users)

Comment: Nope, i would like to call this method http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users with id valorized and it's not working

Comment: @system, I'd have to guess that is a documentation bug.  Otherwise, how is what you are looking at different from the one I pointed out?

Comment: @systempuntoout: To do a vectorized list of users like this: `/users/23234;241462`. Though you're right, according to the documentation `id=23234;241462` should work as well.

Comment: i was writing about a documentation bug too :).

Comment: @codeka@JJnguy yes, your suggestions are right, i knew that way.